# Neither am I / me neither in a specific context

Tags: grammar

A friend of mine and I were talking about a party that we've had today and he told me the following:

> I won't have dinner at home, lol.

And I replied:

> Neither am I.

Based on these topics, [Using either, neither and too](http://www.5minuteenglish.com/mar4.htm) and [Is the statement "Neither am I" right?](http://www.englishforums.com/English/IsStatementNeitherRight/vpzll/post.htm), my answer was not wrong at all in myself comprehension.

I want to know your opinion, is the above wrong? If so, why? And what's the *correctiest* way to express equality in that situation?

Comment: It's wrong. You have to echo the head verb in what your friend says. Since that's *will* (after you 'uncontract' *won't*) you say: *Neither **will** I*. You can also say *me neither*, or if you want to be snooty *nor I*.

Comment: Convert your comment into an answer, @StoneyB, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To:

> I won't [=**will** not] have dinner at home, lol.

The correct answer should be:

> Neither **will** I.

But:

> I'm not [=**am** not] in a mood to go out for dinner tonight.
>
> Neither **am** I. I think I'll just stay home.

- Another option that works for both examples is "me neither."

> I won't have dinner at home, lol.
>
> Me neither.

And

> I'm not in a mood to go out for dinner tonight.
>
> Me neither. I think I'll just stay home.

Answer (score 0):

Me neither is less formal then Neither am I. Except for that I think there is no difference.
<>

Neither am I should be seen as:

```
Neither <verb> I.
```

For example

```
I didn't do my homework.
Neither did I.
```

Comment: "Me neither" is applicable to any negative situation (I don't/won't/can't/haven't/etc.). "Neither am I" only works when the other person is using "to be" in some way.