# Using "Neither am I" to introduce an additional comment

Tags: grammar

I was wondering whether I can use "neither am I" to add an other comment to a statement. For example,

> I am not ignorant to the shortcomings ..., neither am I blind to the
>   negative consequences ....

In my opinion, it is somehow different to

[Neither am I / me neither in a specific context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166447/neither-am-i-me-neither-in-a-specific-context?newreg=df553b64fc9b458e985307b00c6e91c9)

but I could be wrong. Can at least someone tell me whether it sounds weird?

Comment: No, it sounds fine, and it isn't any different from 'Neither am I' on its own.

Comment: Covered comprehensively at ["Not once he would" vs. "not once would he"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88324/not-once-he-would-vs-not-once-would-he) (the example 'Neither is there the necessity to be excited over such triviality.' is included in Blessed Geek's answer).